# Inventory System - Proper way to keep track of status and location of parts

Tags: php, mysql, inventory

If I have a table called group:

```
[Part_one_id|Part_two_id|Part_three_id|status|location]
     1            7           6        ready     long/lat
     2            2           9        in-use    long/lat
```

And there are three separate part tables for each part:

```
     Part one                     Part two                   Part three
[id][measurement]             [id][pressure]               [id][temperature]
```

Which way should I track location and status?

1. Any time the status updates on the group, run another query to update the status and location of the parts in their own tables
2. If I need to find out where a location is I look at what group it is in and pull the current location

Comment: You could do this with a trigger, or if you are using an MVC framework with active record, do an AfterSave update to your arbitrary tables.

Comment: I would go with option 2. It doesn't require a trigger and it centralizes the location of the items in the group in one table, rather than adding duplicate information across the three parts tables.

Comment: @Eric but if I want to simply list out the parts and their locations with a select. I need to iterate the list in PHP after i get it from the database to find the current location.

Comment: That's what JOINs are for :-) You would write the query something like this: SELECT Part_one.id, Part_one.measurement, group.location FROM Part_one LEFT JOIN group ON Part_one.id = group.Part_one_id. For the purposes of this query, each part listing would be combined with the location data in the result returned.

Comment: But  because of what im tracking I need to scan the past location changes to see what the status is. If a report was to "change a part" the status is now "out-of-service" if the report is to "relocate" status is "stand-by". Cant do that with joins

Answer (score 1):

There are a few big issues I see with your table structure off the bat.

1. You should never have a table with something like: part1_id, part2_id,... Because if you want to add more parts to a row than the original design you need to add columns, with a large table this is untractable. Instead use a many to many relationship with a join table.
2. You should probably audit locations so you have snapshots of where it is at any given point in time. That means you should have an audit table that has part_id, location_id, created, modified  and a location table that has lat/long.

As far as the answer to the question itself. I don't particularly like MySQL triggers because the syntax isn't that great and they don't do as much as they do in other databases like PostgreSQL or Oracle. That being said, the appealing thing about triggers in this instance would be that the trigger would execute in the same transaction as the update/insert that triggers it, so you would get that business rule for free. However, depending on what you use to access your database you can just start a transaction and not end it until you've done your auditing inserts.

Ultimately what your tables would change to look like would be:

group: id, name, created, modified, status

part_group: part_id, group_id, created, modified

location: id, lat, long

group_location: group_id, location_id, created, modified

Then the most recently created group_location would point to your current location for a given group.